# How to recover from 777 permission on root in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS WSL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I tried to run sudo command the following error shows up:

sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I also tried 'pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers' but it showed the following error: Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory

Is there a way to get back to normalcy without reinstallation?

I tried explorer.exe . in wsl and it shows all the ubuntu files in windows so can i change file permissions from Windows?
Please Help...

Comment: FWIW: Manipulating the permission bits of important files, as is `/etc/sudoers`, has a tendency to cause trouble. Restore with `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` for this particular file under Ubuntu (WSL is a modified Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Open window cmd run as admin. Then `wsl -u root`, Here you can reset all permissions

```
chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

Now you can open linux terminal in wsl sudo will work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my [recent question](https://superuser.com/q/1632054/1270397), you can use `wsl -u root` from the Windows command prompt to enter into root mode (bypassing sudo). Then you can run the normal `chmod` command on `/etc/sudoers` to reset your permissions. In my case, I had deleted my sudoers file, but the same `wsl` command allowed me to create a new file and get back into my wsl with `sudo` working again.