# Are there any usable Linux/Ubuntu recovery methods for WSL?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As [a previous StackOverflow question alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66550308/13020139), is it possible to use any normal recovery tools (live booting from usb, grub command line, etc.) on a WSL program and, if so, how?

For instance, if one accidentally modified `sudo` permissions and could no longer use sudo without getting the “/etc/sudoers is world writable” error. In this case, how would one revert the `/etc/sudoers` permissions, since this `chmod` command itself needs `sudo` and so normally you would need to do a live boot to change file permissions?

**Update**: For my own “proof of concept” purposes I initially tried to mount my Windows drive (with WSL) from a completely separate Ubuntu computer to see if I could change the sudoers file permissions from there.

Although it seemed as if I was able to change the permissions from Ubuntu, once I got back into Windows and WSL, the sudoers file showed as corrupted (garbage `ls -lah` data). I used the information provided by [@user1686 in comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1632054/are-there-any-usable-linux-ubuntu-recovery-methods-for-wsl?noredirect=1#comment2492691_1632054) and [@NotTheDr01ds in an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632097/167207) to access WSL as root and then create a new sudoers file with correct permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your "for instance", WSL easily allows you to start the default instance as root (without a password) with `wsl -u root` from PowerShell or CMD or, if it's not the default instance, `wsl -d <DistroName> -u root`.  You could then run `visudo` without requiring a sudo password.

WSL also allows "backups" of the entire filesystem using `wsl --export <DistroName> <filename.tar>`.  This could be likely be automated to create a backup schedule using a script in Windows Task Manager.  Recovery would then be a matter of restoring to the latest using `wsl --import` (see `wsl --help` for more info).  Note that imported instances do not store the default username, so you would also need to create an `/etc/wsl.conf` with a [user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#user) section.